# Вывод значений разных объектов класса

Tags: c++-cli

Есть класс logic

```
#pragma once
namespace tetstst {
    public ref class logic {
    private:
        char* name;
    public:
        logic();
        int score;
        void    setScore(int score);
        int     getScore() { return score; };

        void    setName(char*);
        char*   getName() { return name; };

        ~logic();
    };
}
```

В классе Source создаются два объекта logic.

```
#pragma once
#include "logic.h"

namespace tetstst {
    public ref class Sourse{
    public:
        Sourse();
        logic player1;
        logic player2;
    };
}
```

В диалоговое окно должно выводится значение `score` выбранного игрока.
Как можно задать, чьё значение брать при выводе? Т.е. выбрав `player1` должно выводится значение `player1`, в случае выбора `player2` должно выводится значение `player2` в то же окно.

Сейчас вывожу значение с помощью

```
textBox1->Text = sourse->player1.getScore().ToString();
```

но как переделать его на выбор текущего игрока?

Comment: Это какой-то CLI что ли? Нет **ref** в нормальных плюсах.

Comment: Я планирую расширять кол-во игроков, а для каждого нового игрока прописывать свой if это плохой вариант.

Comment: В этом и стоит вопрос. Как выводить в окно очки выбранного игрока? Создать функцию типа setActivePlayer, в который передаю объект, и обращаться к ней? Как это выглядит наглядно?